# ${\rm 2D}$ isotropic oscillator: Is ${\rm SO(4)}$ a subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(4,{\rm R})$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Consider the ${\rm 2D}$ isotropic oscillator. The hamiltonian is $$H=\frac{1}{2}(p_x^2+p_y^2+x^2+y^2)$$ and the phase space is $4$ dimensional. In this case, the set of all linear canonical transformations that preserve the form of Hamilton's equations form a group ${\rm Sp}(4,{\rm R})$. On the other hand, the group of orthogonal transformations ${\rm SO(4)}$, in the phase space, leaves the hamiltonian $H$ invariant. Now, there can be a subset of canonical transformations that leaves the Hmiltnian invariant in addition to preserving the form of Hamilton's equations.

- Will it be correct to assert that ${\rm SO(4)}$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(4,{\rm R})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $SO(2n,\mathbb{F})\subseteq Sp(2n,\mathbb{F})$ [understood via their standard embedding into $GL(2n,\mathbb{F})$] is only true for $n=1$. This fact can be proved by considering the corresponding [Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group).

Specifically, $Sp(4,\mathbb{R})$  is (the double cover of) the [restricted anti de Sitter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $SO^+(3,2;\mathbb{R})$, cf. e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/248009/11127).

Comment: So that would mean, there are some ${\rm SO(4)}$ transformations in the phase space that are not canonical transformations?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.